# How to align, enlarge and center the following contents?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, arrays, alignment

I want to

- align `2` and `4` with the red lines on their right.
- vertically enlarge the middle column to provide well balanced space for its contents.
- vertically center the contents in the third column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,varwidth,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}m{0.3\linewidth}|>{\centering}m{0.3\linewidth}|>{\centering}m{0.2\linewidth}|}\hline
A pair of points & Slope & Type \tabularnewline\hline\hline
$
\begin{array}{@{}c@{(}c@{}c@{,}c@{}c@{)}c@{}}
A&&2&&-3&\\
B&&-1&&4&
\end{array}$ & 
$
\begin{aligned}
m   &= \frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}\\
    &= \frac{4-(-3)}{-1-2}\\
    &= -\frac{7}{3}
\end{aligned}
$ & Decreasing \tabularnewline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Note: My code above might be semantically wrong.  Any modification is welcome.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of changing "$500" to "500 TeX.SE rep points", as I felt that the original announcement was, while eye-catching, also rather misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

1. No vertical rule, no double rules.
2. No `m` type, one can use `w{c}`.
3. Use a local macro in order to ease inputting the coordinates.
4. Add some vertical space between the points.
5. Increase the value of `\jot` in order to increase the distance between rows in `aligned`.
6. Add some vertical space below the middle rule and above the bottom rule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  w{c}{0.33333\columnwidth}
  @{}
  w{c}{0.33333\columnwidth}
  @{}
  w{c}{0.33333\columnwidth}
  @{}
}
\toprule
A pair of points & Slope & Type \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
$\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\point}[3]{#1&(&#2&,{}&#3&)}
\begin{array}{ r r r l r r }
  \point{A}{2}{-3} \\[2ex]
  \point{B}{-1}{4}
\end{array}$
& 
$\addtolength{\jot}{6pt}\begin{aligned}
m   &= \frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}\\
    &= \frac{4-(-3)}{-1-2}\\
    &= -\frac{7}{3}
\end{aligned}$
&
Decreasing \\
\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When would I need to use column type w instead of m to have vertical centering?

Answer (score 3):

A approach that uses `stackengine` in the left column, and eliminates the `m` columns to achieve vertical centering.  Also `\addstackgap` was used to add vertical buffer above/below the middle column.

```
\documentclass[preview,varwidth,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begingroup\tabcolsep=30pt
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
A pair of points & Slope & Type \tabularnewline\hline\hline
\Matrixstack[r]{
A(&2,& -3)\\
B(&-1,& 4)
} & 
\addstackgap[5pt]{$
\begin{aligned}
m   &= \frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}\\[4pt]
    &= \frac{4-(-3)}{-1-2}\\[4pt]
    &= -\frac{7}{3}
\end{aligned}$}
 & Decreasing \tabularnewline\hline
\end{tabular}\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way with `cellspace`, in the place of `\arraystretch`, and `\multirow`:

```
\documentclass[preview,varwidth,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[a5paper, margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{S{m{#1}}}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|wc{0.3\linewidth}| >{\centering}M{0.3\linewidth}|wc{0.2\linewidth}|}\hline
A pair of points & Slope & Type \tabularnewline\hline\hline
\multirow{3.9}{=}{\centering$\begin{matrix}
A (\phantom{-}2,-3)\\
B(-1,\phantom{-}4)
\end{matrix}$} &
$ \begin{aligned}
m &= \frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}\\
    &= \frac{4-(-3)}{-1-2}\\
    &= -\frac{7}{3}
\end{aligned} $ & 
\multirow{4}{=}{\centering Decreasing} \tabularnewline\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very basic proposal, mostly based on `empheq` and `booktabs`. It requires little tweaking to reach the expected result. The alignment of the left column contents is done using `\hphantom`s

```
% arara: lwpdflatex
\documentclass[preview,varwidth,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}\toprule
A pair of points & Slope & Type\\\midrule
\parbox{0.2\paperwidth}{
\begin{empheq}{align*}
    A(\hphantom{-}2,-3)\\
    B(-1,\hphantom{-}4)
\end{empheq}
} 
& 
\parbox{0.2\paperwidth}{
 \begin{empheq}{align*}
 m   &= \frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}\\
     &= \frac{4-(-3)}{-1-2}\\
     &= -\frac{7}{3}
 \end{empheq}
}
 & Decreasing\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought you wanted to align the 2 and the 4, but now I guess it is not your objective

Answer (score 2):

With `cellspace` and `adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[a5paper, margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering}O{m{#1}}}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
{
    \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{| c | Oc | c |}
    \hline
\text{A pair of points}
                & \text{Slope}
                        & Type  \tabularnewline
    \hline\hline
\adjustbox{valign=c,array=rrr}      % <-------
{%
A( &  2, & -3)\\
B( & -1, &  4)\\
}   &   $\begin{aligned}
    m & =  \frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}\\
      & =  \frac{4-(-3)}{-1-2}\\
      & = -\frac{7}{3}
    \end{aligned}$  &   Decreasing  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or with `makecell`, `tabularx` and `adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[a5paper, margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{| C | C | C |}
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\text{A pair of points}
                & \text{Slope}
                        & Type  \tabularnewline
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
\adjustbox{valign=c,array=rrr}       % <-------
{%
A( &  2, & -3)\\
B( & -1, &  4)\\
}   &   $\begin{aligned}
    m & =  \frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}\\
      & =  \frac{4-(-3)}{-1-2}\\
      & = -\frac{7}{3}
    \end{aligned}$  &   Decreasing  \\
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]
or with `booktabs` and `adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[a5paper, margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
{
    \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{ c c  c }
    \toprule
\text{A pair of points}
                & \text{Slope}
                        & Type  \tabularnewline
    \midrule
\adjustbox{valign=c,array=rrr}      % <-------
{%
A( &  2, & -3)\\
B( & -1, &  4)\\
}   &   $\begin{aligned}
    m & =  \frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}\\
      & =  \frac{4-(-3)}{-1-2}\\
      & = -\frac{7}{3}
    \end{aligned}$  &   Decreasing  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- use a `tabularx` environment and a centered version of the `X` column type for all three columns
- drop the instruction `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}`
- for column #1, set `\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}` and use an `array` with three `r`-type columns; make sure to insert a bit of whitespace between "2," and "-3"
- for column #2, keep using an `aligned` environment, but increase the value of `jot`
- no need to do anything special for the contents of column #3
- omit all vertical rules and use few, but well-spaced, horizontal rules with the help of the macros of the `booktabs` package

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,varwidth,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% new:
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} CCC @{}}
\toprule
A pair of points & Slope & Type \\
\midrule
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
$\begin{array}{rrr}
  A(& 2,&\,-3) \\
  B(&-1,&   4)
\end{array}$  &
\addtolength\jot{4pt}
$\begin{aligned}
  m &=  \frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A} \\
    &=  \frac{4-(-3)}{-1-2} \\
    &= -\frac{7}{3}
\end{aligned}$  & 
Decreasing   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass[preview,varwidth,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{Q[m,c,0.3\linewidth]Q[m,c,0.3\linewidth]Q[m,c,0.2\linewidth]}
\toprule
A pair of points & Slope & Type \\
\midrule
$\begin{tblr}{colsep=0pt, colspec={rrr}}
A(& 2,\,&-3) \\
B(&-1,\,& 4) \\
\end{tblr}$ & 
$\begin{aligned}
m   &= \frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}\\
    &= \frac{4-(-3)}{-1-2}\\
    &= -\frac{7}{3}
\end{aligned}
$ & Decreasing \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]