# tabular: In a centered column, how to make all the entries (except the header) virtually have the same width to make them left-aligned?

Tags: tables, width

For this MWE, how to make `D_M` virtually have the same width of `K_{emf}` in order to be left-aligned with `K_{emf}` while keeping both centered with respect to the column margins?

Generally speaking, how to do it for any number of rows (below the header) without having to manually detect the widest entry of the respective column?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,ragged2e,booktabs,lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \tabcolsep0pt
    \begin{tabular}{
            >{\Centering}m{0.2\linewidth}
        }
        \toprule
        Symbol\\
        \midrule
        $D_M$\\
        $K_{emf}$\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \tabcolsep0pt
    \begin{tabular}{
            >{\quad}l<{\quad}
        }
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{Symbol}\\
        \midrule
        $D_M$\\
        $K_{\mathit{emf}}$\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like how simple your answers are. No need to burn the house to kill the spider :)

Comment: For the `m` column used in my question, this `>{\hspace{2ex}\RaggedRight}m{0.2\linewidth}<{\hspace{2ex}}` doesn't work. May I know why?

Comment: adding hspace at the start and end of the text in a paragraph has no effect on the width of the entry as the text is line broken to the specified width, I don't see why you would use  m here, there is no linebreaking and m loses baseline alignment with other columns. @Diaa

Comment: I need to have vertical centering of the cell content. I would be grateful to propose an approach for such a result.

Comment: @Diaa Bernard's answer uses m, so you could move the tick to the other answer if you prefer (I will cope:-)   the whole point of this answer is _not_ to use m, using vertically centred cells with subscripted variables will produce potentially very uneven results with the text not following any baseline why do you want that?

Comment: I believe you answered my question to help me not to gain virtual internet credit :) so that's why I ask to further understand not argue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I thought I was posting a complement to my answer, but didn't see first I was editing *your* answer, so I had to re-edit it to copy-paste at the right place. Quite sorry. Won't do it again!

Comment: @Bernard no worries: I have done that to other people's posts in the past as well, it's easily done:-)

Comment: A quick question if you don't mind: for `tabularx`, does this, for example, `>{\hspace{2ex}\RaggedRight\hsize=1.6\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X<{\hspace{2ex}}` mean that an additional space of `2ex` will be added to the column width after it is calculated by `\hsize`? Or it will behave like `m` column of explicit width as you explained earlier!

Comment: @Diaa the hspace make no sense in an m  or X column, they will not affect the column width or the content as space at the start of a paragraph is discarded.

Comment: I hope your patience is not over yet :) but what is the difference between wrapping the subscript in `\mathit` or leaving it as I did? Visually speaking, I think both look the same for me.

Comment: @Diaa it looks completely different look at the vast ocean of white space between the m and f in your image compared to the one here.  `\mathit` selects the text italic font, for use in math so is a font with spacing designed for words. the default font  is math italic which is a completely different font with slightly different letter shapes and very different inter-letter spacing. Compare `$diff$` and `$\mathit{diff}$`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that with the `stackengine` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,ragged2e,booktabs,lipsum}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

    \tabcolsep0pt
    \begin{tabular}{
            >{\Centering}m{0.2\linewidth}
        }
        \toprule
        Symbol\\
        \midrule
    \Centerstack[l]{ $D_M$\\
        $K_{emf}$}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To have also coloured rows, you can use this other solution, based on `eqparbox` add this code to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{eqparbox} 
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1][l]{$\displaystyle#2$}}
```

and this for the tabular:

```
    \begin{tabular}{
            >{\Centering}m{0.2\linewidth}
        }
        \toprule
        Symbol\\
        \midrule
        \eqmathbox{D_M}\\
        \rowcolor{yellow}\eqmathbox{K_{emf}}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: I know it is not stated in the question but if I have this problem https://pastebin.com/zzg2G9gS, how can I make `$K_{emf}$` inside `\Centerstack` be placed in the second row and colored yellow by the `\rowcolors`?

Comment: Actually, with \Centerstack, rows 2 and 3 are combined within a single row. I'll post in a moment another possibility with `eqparbox`, if I've well undertood what you want.

Comment: Many thanks for your consideration to answer a follow-up question in the comments. You can find it here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/574630/2288 as a separate clear question to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565356/2288), the following also works using `adjustbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,ragged2e,booktabs,lipsum,adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    \tabcolsep0pt
    \begin{tabular}{
            >{\Centering}m{0.2\linewidth}
        }
        \toprule
        Symbol\\
        \midrule
        \adjustbox{tabular = l}{%
            $D_M$\\
            $K_{emf}$\\
        }\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off topic: (i) more correct is `$K_{\mathrm{emf}}$` (`e`, `m` and `f` are not variables, but abbreviation, I assume), (ii) please, can you show the use of the `\rowcolor` in your solution?

Comment: @Zarko I just came here to make the same comment when yours appeared:-), or `\mathit` as in my answer, Diaa that f is like  a poke in the eye:-) never use math italic for a multi-letter word, it is designed to separate the letters so they are not a word but a product of  1-letter variables.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you are right!

Comment: For rowcolors, assume I have this document https://pastebin.com/ntL5a7Mv, then I need to left-align the symbols while centering them with respect to the column margins. I should have asked this as a separate question, but I tried to test Bernard generosity first :) I took your note about the subscripts @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @Zarko I posted my question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/574630/2288.